# python adding a title row to csv output file

Tags: python, csv, header

I have a python script that gets data from a database and outputs a csv file. Now I'm trying to add a header row containing titles for each of the columns. What do I need to add so that it outputs an initial row ahead of the db output (I'm quite a newbie to python, so I got stuck in this part and couldn't find the info I needed)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a [`DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), you can just call [`writeheader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader).